# Tabbar React Native

Tags: react, react-native, flexbox

Estou com dificuldade para posicionar um `component` de `tabbar` que estou fazendo.

**Home.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View, Text, ScrollView} from 'react-native'
import Header from './../components/Header'
import Card from './../components/Card'
import TabBar from './../components/TabBar'

class Home extends Component{
    render(){
        const {scrollContent, tab, scroll} = styles

        return(
            <View>
                <Header />

                <View>
                    <ScrollView>
                        <Card />
                    </ScrollView>
                </View> 

                <TabBar />
            </View> 
        )
    }
}



export default Home
```

**TabBar.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text} from 'react-native'

const TabBar = () => {
    const {tab} = styles

    return(
        <View style={tab}>

        </View>
    )
}

const styles = {
    tab: {
        height: 50,
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        flexDirection: 'row'
    }
}

export default TabBar
```

Se eu deixo com o `position: 'absolute'`, ele some da tela, se eu tiro, ele fica a baixo do meu component `card`.

A ideia é que ele fique no final da tela, fixo.

Comment: Ao setar o position absolute o width perde a referencia, então acho que é só adicionar um width 100% e tirar o flexDirection que não tem serventia nenhuma ai, caso não funcione o problema está no container.

Comment: @FelipeDuarte Fiz o que falou e continua sumido :/ o container nao tem nenhum estilo definido

Comment: Mas para onde ele vai?, consegue inspecionar e mostrar a estrutura já compilada no navegador?

Comment: @FelipeDuarte Cara, eu consegui, valeu mesmo em, voce falou do `container` entao fui e coloquei no `container: {height: '100%'}` e ai ficou lá no final.

Comment: Aí sim haha, respondi para ficar mais organizado.

Answer (score 0):

Ao setar `position:absolute` sob um `container` é necessário observar se o mesmo preenche a altura da tela, geralmente o `document.body` inicial preenche, então basta adicioná-lo no final com `bottom:0`, exemplo...

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
}
div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div>
    Footer
</div>

</body>
```

Caso o `container` não ocupe a altura completa, basta adicionar `height: 100%`